# Consensus number of memory-to-memory swap

Tags: concurrency, consensus

I think that consensus number of mem-to-mem-swap(a,b) operation which atomically swaps the values between shared locations a and b (shared R/W memory) is **infinite** , but I'm having trouble proving it.
I thought about implementing **CAS** with mem-to-mem-swap but comparing atomically is problematic, I think there is straightforward consensus protocol but I can't think about one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Theorem 10 (Figure 13) of the paper ["Wait-Free Synchronization
"](https://cs.brown.edu/~mph/Herlihy91/p124-herlihy.pdf) by Herlihy, 1991.

> Theorem 10: An array of registers with memory-to-meory swap has infinite
>   consensus number.
>
> Proof: The protocol is shown in Figure 13. The processes share an array of
>   registers $a[1 \ldots n]$ whose elements are initialized to $0$ and a single register $r$, initialized to $1$. The first process to swap $1$ into $a$ wins.

[image: memory-to-memory-swap]

Footnote 4 of this paper remarks that:

> The memory-to-memory swap should not be confused with the read-modify-write swap; the former exchanges the values of two public registers, while the latter exchanges the value of a public register with a processor’s private register.